# One inch black bar on lower portion of my screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, screen

I've noticed a black line on my desktop, and I can't seems to figure out how to remove it. I've restarted my computer several times, relaunched my Finder through "Force Quit," and searched through my application to remove anything I don't use anymore. I don't think it's a display card issue because I'm able to move applications behind it, and they would still appear, but just with the line in front of it. I take really good care of my laptop, so I don't think it's due to external damage. And, my cursor can move over the line. If it helps, I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) and using version 10.13.6 of macOS High Sierra. If anyone could help me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

[UPDATE: The image is a screenshot and the bar disappeared with a pixel checking program, but still there after changing the desktop picture and adjusting the display profile.]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If that is a screenshot, the bar is programmatic - something is generating it. If it's a photo, then it could be hardware, but in a screenshot, even the graphics card thinks it exists.

Comment: My mid2012 also showed such bars from time to time. Sometimes they were flashing. I am pretty sure that was a GPU driver issue. When you boot into recovery mode, are the bars still there?

Comment: What happens if you change the desktop background to a solid color, does it go away? If so it may be the desktop background picture.

Comment: @Tetsujin: The picture I attached is a screenshot. I think it's programmatic, how would I go about find which program is causing it?                                                    @ n1000: I'm glad to hear I'm not the only one with this issue. However, the bar on my computer doesn't flash, it's consistent even after restarting the computer and placing Finder into recovery mode.                                                                                  @ Steve Chambers: I just tried a pixel checking program with solid colors and the bar goes away- for white, red, blue, etc.

Comment: Change the desktop picture. Test.

Comment: @Tetsujin : I changed the desktop picture and it's still there. It seems like th bar is above my browser but below my curser because my mail, browser, or other applications go under it, but I can move my curser over it.

Comment: hmm... odd. Still feels like it's something programatic, maybe a vestigial floater from an app. Does it follow you if you either swap to a new Space with no apps on it, or open something in fullscreen? Also test booting to Safe Mode & logging into a brand new account.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use a pixel checking program in order to identify the issue is whether related to actual hardware level dead pixel issue or a software based issue.[Dead pixel checking online tool](http://lcdtech.info/en/tests/dead.pixel.htm) is freely available tool to check the issue. There are number of tools to find out these type of issue on the internet.

Comment: @ Binoyya: I performed the pixel checking program and the bar disappeared for all of the colors. How would I go about determining/fixing the software based issue?

Comment: Ill answer you in this way, I am using MBP with mojavi and from system preference --> Displays --> Built in display --> Color. from this path you will see that there are some different color schemes. Do try out a new suitable color system other that the one you applied right now.

Comment: @ Binoyya: Thank you for the suggestion, but the bar is still there with each of the display profile options and still there when I change the background. I can drag my webpage under it and my curser over it. I can't understand what is causing it.